# Error openlayers : Json not displayed

Tags: javascript, php, openlayers-3

Sorry for my english but I use google translation .
I am trying to develop a web application with openlayers 3 .
The principle : With php pick in the database gis layers. 
My problem: 
The json will not be displayed in the interface , I think it's probably a problem in javascript but I can not find.

My php script works correctly and return me the geojson.

Thank you for helping me,
See you soon

```
<html>
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Smiddest</title>

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.17.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ol3-layerswitcher.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.css"  media="screen,projection">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
    <body>
        <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['mem_id']) AND $userinfo['mem_id'] == $_SESSION['mem_id']) {
                ?>

    <header>
        <?php include 'header.php' ?>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s8 m8 l8">
                <div id="map" class="map"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col s4 m4 4">
                <div class="col s6 m6 l6"></div>
                <div class="col s6 m6 l6">
                    <?php
                    $date = date("d/m/Y");
                    Print('<div class="heure">' . "$date" . '</div>');
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>    

        <!-- Fin du isset -->
        <?php
            }
        ?>

        <script src="js/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/ol3-layerswitcher.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>   

         <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();    

    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Fond de cartes',
                layers: [

                    new ol.layer.Vector({
                        title: 'Chemins',
                        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                        url: 'getData.php',
                        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                        projection: 'EPSG:3857',

                        }),
                        }),

                   new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'MapBox Street',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: true,
                    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                        url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiamF1ZnJ5IiwiYSI6ImNpcmVsbjg1YjAwMGhpY200b2xudmQ3bmUifQ.vSOJfU9DMMEa7JDss5TDQA'
                    })
                }),

                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    title: 'Fond OSM',
                    type: 'base',
                    visible: true,
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                }),   
                ]
            }),

        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-0.57, 45.22]),
            zoom: 10
        })
    });

    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Légende'
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
```

php :

```
<?php
try{
      $bdd = new PDO ("pgsql:host=localhost;port=8356;dbname=BDD_SMIDDEST;user=postgres") or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));
      $bdd->exec("SET NAMES utf8");
      $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}

   catch(Exeption $e){
      die("Erreur!".$e->getMessage());
   }

$qry = $bdd->prepare("SELECT dgs_id, ST_ASGeoJSON(geom) AS geojson FROM departements_geofla_sage");
$qry->execute();

// Renvoit un chemin au format GeoJSON
$geojson = array("type" => "FeatureCollection",
"features" => array()
);

// Ajouter un tronçon au tableau GeoJSON
while($row=$qry->fetch()) 
{
$feature = array("type" => "Feature",
"geometry" => json_decode($row["geojson"], true),
"crs" => array(
"type" => "EPSG",
"properties" => array("code" => "3857")
),
"properties" => array(
"dgs_id" => $row["dgs_id"]
)
);
// Ajouter un tableau d"éléments au tableau de collection d"éléments
array_push($geojson["features"], $feature);
}
// Fermeture de la connexion
$bdd = null;
// Renvoyer le résultat
echo json_encode($geojson);
?>
```

The geojson :

[Json Valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9rWj.png)

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: Show your `index.html|.php` and javascript file.

Comment: Use ol-debug.js instead for error reporting.

Comment: @BenJfry have you checked if your geojson data are valid, can you post an example here ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, here is the json valid image in post

Comment: You should validate if it's a [GeoJSON](http://geojsonlint.com/) file.

Comment: Great, thank you. Json now displays correctly in Qgis but not in the web interface. I edited my post with the updated codes.

Comment: Then post here (or somewhere else) a piece of GeoJSON string.

Comment: Problem solved , it was a concern of srid . Thank you !